# Searching a database for a string and taking relevant information VB

Tags: mysql, sql, vb.net, search

I want to be able to search my database for a product name or product ID number and then load any relevant information regarding the product into text boxes.

My current code has no build errors however it doesn't seem to return any information. Its probably just something small and I'm being an idiot but I cant fathom the problem.

```
 Private Sub btnSearchProducts_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnSearchProducts.Click
    ds.Clear()

    If txtProductName.Text = "" And txtProductID.Text = "" Then
        MessageBox.Show("Please enter either a Product ID or Product Name..", "Authentication Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)

    Else
        If txtProductID.Text <> "" Then
            For Each ch As Char In txtProductID.Text
                If Not Char.IsDigit(ch) Then
                    txtProductID.Clear()
                    MsgBox("Please enter a valid Product ID. Only integers are a valid input", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
                    Exit Sub
                End If
            Next
        End If

        ' Connect to DB

        Dim conn As New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection()
        conn.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=D:\Computing Project\Database1.accdb"
        Dim Command As New OleDb.OleDbCommand

        Try

            Dim sql As String = "SELECT * FROM tbl_stock WHERE S_ID = '" & txtProductID.Text & "'OR S_ProductName = '" & txtProductName.Text & "'"
            Dim sqlCom As New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand(sql)

            'Open Database Connection
            sqlCom.Connection = conn
            conn.Open()

            da = New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter(sql, conn)
            da.Fill(ds, "Stock")

            Dim sqlRead As System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataReader = sqlCom.ExecuteReader()

            If sqlRead.Read() Then
                txtProductID.Text = CInt(ds.Tables("Stock").Rows(0).Item(0))
                txtProductName.Text = ds.Tables("Stock").Rows(0).Item(3)
                txtProductPrice.Text = "£" & CDec(ds.Tables("Stock").Rows(0).Item(2))
            Else
                If txtProductID.Text <> "" Then
                    MsgBox("Sorry, " & txtProductID.Text & " is not a valid Product ID", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
                    txtProductID.Text = ""
                End If
                If txtProductName.Text <> "" Then
                    MsgBox("Sorry, " & txtProductName.Text & " is not a valid Product Name", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
                    txtProductName.Text = ""
                End If
            End If
        Catch ex As Exception
        End Try
    End If
End Sub
```

Any help is much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

A few thoughts about this, that might point you to the right direction.

1. It looks that you are combining two different logical processes.  Filling a dataset, then trying to read from the same query again.  Rather than calling out to "read" for your if statement.  Look for the count of rows on ds.Tables[0] that might resolve the immediate issue.
2. Please have a look at parameterized SQL Queries, building from raw user entry allows for malicious actions and all efforts should be taken to avoid it if you can.
3. Looking at your query, you are looking for an exact match on ID, or name.  You might switch to a LIKE operation on the name rather than an exact match.

Comment: Thanks for the pointers, unfortunately regarding the first point Im either not certain I understand what you mean or how I would go about doing it. I also get the follwoign appearing in the errors list when I run my program "A first chance exception of type 'System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException' occurred in System.Data.dll" any more help youd be able to give? @Mitchel Sellers